# Ending a stored procedure in .sql file

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this in an SQL file and I assumed that `end` is going to end the stored procedure:

```
create procedure Test4
as
begin
  select * from People
end
select * from Region
```

But instead, I got "Command completed successfully" and when I looked at the stored definition, I got:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Test4]
as
begin
  select * from People
end
select * from Region
```

So what's the use of BEGIN/END in a stored procedure in SQL Server if it isn't to actually END it?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [MSDN post on CREATE PROCEDURE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx), the BEGIN-END block is optional:

> { [ BEGIN ] sql_statement [;] [ ...n ] [ END ] } One or more
>   Transact-SQL statements comprising the body of the procedure. You can
>   use the optional BEGIN and END keywords to enclose the statements. For
>   information, see the Best Practices, General Remarks, and Limitations
>   and Restrictions sections that follow.

I just ran a test against MS SQL Server and noticed that if I include a query before the `GO` keyword after the `END` it gets included in the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test]

AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Test1
END
-- This gets included in the procedure
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Test2
GO
```

Whereas if I type it after the `GO`, the query is left out of the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test]

AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Test1
END
GO
-- This gets chopped off when I open the procedure for editing later
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Test2
```

Comment: It turns out that begin/end are purely for decoration purposes then. The real begin is the AS and the real 'end' is the GO.

Comment: More precisely,  the linked documentation for `CREATE PROCEDURE`, under "Limitations and Restrictions", says: "The `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement cannot be combined with other Transact-SQL statements in a single batch." - and `GO` is the batch separator (in SSMS and SSDT) so that explains it. (As for "why?" - I assume this can be blamed on a shortsighted design decision when sprocs were originally added to SQL Server (perhaps during Sybase years?) and they never got around to fixing it because it ultimately still isn't _that big_ a problem... just an annoying inconsistency.