# Syntax for ending Procedure creation in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, sql-server-2019

I want to create a temporary procedure in a Begin-End-Block and after that run the procedure with different parameters. I have to do this because i dont want to create lasting procedures on the server but i have some problems to get the syntax right.
What i want is somethin like this:

```
begin

    create temp proc
    declare some variables
    call proc multiple times
end;
```

Which looks something like this at the moment but i get syntax errors:

```
use mycontext
begin
    CREATE PROC #my_procedure @period_name varchar(10), @from date, @to date
    AS
    begin
        VeryLongMergeStatement;
    end;
    GO

    declare @today date= GETDATE();
    declare @other_date date = EOMONTH(GETDATE(), (-1 - 3));
    declare more dates

    #my_procedure 'period_title' @today @other_date
end;
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943768/ending-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-file) but it did not realy help me. I tried a lot of diferent combinations of semicololons,m with begin and end, without it, with go and without it. It always shows errors.
Its probably just something small but i cant find it.

Comment: There isn't a "ending syntax"; the procedure is the entirety of the batch. The "ending syntax" is the batch ending.

Comment: @Larnu so it is not possible?

Comment: In the above, the error you're getting is because `CREATE PROC` isn't the only statement in the batch; you have a `USE` prior. You also have a `BEGIN` in a separate batch to the `END`; they need to be in the same batch.

Comment: *"so it is not possible?"* Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me. What is the problem you're actually trying to solve here?

Comment: @Larnu i think my first pseudocode explains what i want to to. create a temporary procedure with parameters, create some variables and call the procedure in the same block

Comment: So why do you need a temporary procedure at all? Why not just execute the statement in the first place?

Comment: @Larnu because in reality i have to call the procedure multiple times with different values.

Comment: Then why use a temporary one? Clearly you need to reuse this, so create a procedure you can use in the future.

Comment: @Larnu for different reasons i dont want to create permanent procedures and functions. Realy i know its not a beautiiful solution but i only need to know the syntax.

Comment: *"but i only need to know the syntax"* Well on that front, you already have 2 answers below; but this still has the smell of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227155/discussion-between-goodsnek-and-larnu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create a temporary stored procedure in a programming block.  It is just not allowed, so this returns an error:

```
begin
    create procedure #abc as begin print 2; end;

    print 1;
end;
```

Why?  Well the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is pretty clear:

> The CREATE PROCEDURE statement cannot be combined with other Transact-SQL statements in a single batch.

I should add that a "batch" cannot interrupt a `BEGIN`/`END` block.

So, the simple work-around is to create the stored procedure *outside* the block and then use it:

```
create procedure #abc as begin print 2; end;

begin
    print 1;
    exec #abc;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

YOu have a couple of problems here. Firstly, a `CREATE`/`ALTER PROCEDURE` needs to be the thing in the batch; you have a `USE` statement prior so it's not the only one in the batch. YOu also have a `BEGIN` in a separate batch to the `END`, which will cause an error.

Finally, your syntax for the `EXEC` is wrong, you need to delimit the parameters with commas (`,`). This gives you something like this (parts commented out to make valid SQL):

```sql
USE sandbox;
GO
CREATE PROC #my_procedure @period_name varchar(10), @from date, @to date
AS
BEGIN
    --VeryLongMergeStatement;
    PRINT 1;
END;
GO

declare @today date= GETDATE();
declare @other_date date = EOMONTH(GETDATE(), (-1 - 3));
--declare more dates

EXEC #my_procedure 'period_title', @today, @other_date;
GO

DROP PROC #my_procedure;
```